# How to atone for a ban?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?  (the answer is here, in this post)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

I started using StackOverflow back in college, and was less "internet mature" then. "Internet Mature" meaning I wasn't as savvy on how to find answers for myself.  I ended up asking a bunch of simple, mundane questions on here, and thus, was banned. (I think that's why I was banned. I never heard a reason why).

Since graduating, I've been working at a job as a programmer, and have had some StackOverflow-worthy problems that I cannot get resolved.  Though, it was probably a character-builder since I had to push through it and figure it out myself, or with the help of other websites.  I don't usually answer a lot of questions, mainly because there's almost always a better answer already posted, but I do upvote answers I find helpful on other people's questions.

I would much like to become a full fledged member of the StackOverflow community again.  I have learned my lesson of what questions are worthy of the StackOverflow community, and have learned how to fully use the features StackOverflow has to offer (when I first started, I didn't know how to accept answers lol).

Please let me know what I can do, assuming there is something doable, that will help me clear up any mistakes I've made in the past.

Sincerely,
swl1020

Comment: Reading between the lines I understand you have a question ban. If so, please read [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?  (the answer is here, in this post)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997)

Comment: 50 hours of community service should do it, I think.

Comment: @gobernador By "community service", do we mean picking up trash on the side of a highway or should it be programming-related like contributing to an open-source project?

Comment: @Yawus You know, it was a joke, but contributing to an open-source project doesn't sound too bad. I'm not saying by any means we should require this, it's far beyond our place to require that. Besides, it seems to me like the OP is ready for parole.

Comment: A minor nit, part of atoning is learning the social mores of StackExchange. One of which is, [never ever ever ever including salutations, greetings, taglines, signatures, etc on posts.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GP1s4.png)

Comment: Your question ban is almost 100% due to self-deleted posts.  You should try to *improve* questions instead of deleting them.  I undeleted most that weren't closed first by the community.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8127329/1288 http://stackoverflow.com/q/8097127/1288 http://stackoverflow.com/q/6763235/1288 http://stackoverflow.com/q/6668946/1288

Comment: Check my comments on your other questions.